# Deployment Issue with ChirpStack and Helium: GRPC Permission Denied Error

Tags: iot, lora, lorawan, helium

I am currently encountering an issue while deploying ChirpStack and Helium using the repository provided by disk91 (https://github.com/disk91/helium-chirpstack-community). During the deployment, I have correctly specified my OUI and public key (already registered) and uploaded my .bin key file to the server, setting its path in env.sh.

Despite all services starting up as expected, I am facing a permission issue. When I check the logs using docker logs `docker logs helium-helium-1 | grep -i error`, I receive the following error message:

```
2023-12-15 09:30:05.565  WARN 1 --- [   scheduling-4] e.heliumiot.console.service.NovaService  : GRPC create route error PERMISSION_DENIED: unauthorized request signature
```

This error points to a permissions problem with the GRPC route creation, but I'm uncertain about the specific cause or how to address it. Has anyone else faced a similar issue or can offer insights or solutions? Any assistance in troubleshooting and resolving this error would be immensely helpful.

Thanks for any thoughts!

My steps included:

Specifying my own OUI and public key in the deployment configuration as required by the setup.
Uploading my .bin key file to the server and properly configuring its path in the env.sh file.

Expectation:
Sync my organization data with new backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the error in the helium-helium-1 logs. Here's what I did:

Addressing the "GRPC create route error" issue *
1)Executed the script makeiteasy.sh.
2)Uploaded delegate_keypair.bin to the server.

3)Then, following a step-by-step guide from the website, I updated settings based on the instructions: corrected data in [root /helium/cli]./helium_cli env init and also in env.sh (everywhere, I specified the path to my key).

4)Next, in the `/helium/configuration/helium/configuration.properties` file, I added:

```
##Helium GRPC
helium.grpc.public.key=<your public key from delegate_keypair.bin>
helium.route.oui=<Your OUI>
```

Now, the remaining issue is with the private_key "Impossible to access private key file" *

In the Docker configuration file `/helium/docker-compose.yml` under the helium section (volume), replace keypair.bin with delegate_keypair.bin to deliver it into the container.

After restarting the container, the errors related to the keys disappeared.